# Drop all the subsequent columns after a particular column with some string match python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big dataset and i am working by selecting subset of the entire data in each of these subset i want to drop all the subsequent columns after matching one of the column name's string value that is randomnr.

my df columns looks like this:-

```
    A    B   C   D   E   randomnr   H   I   J   K
```

If this is the subset i am working on i want to drop H I J K columns which are after my common string randomnr and this is the common string match for all the subsets.
for example:- in first subset it can be 'randomnr_abc' and in second subset 'randomnr_123' but all subsets contains 'randomnr'

I am specifically looking to drop these columns for the subset i am working on so that i can use the same code for all the other subsets.
Please help me on this. thanks in advance

Comment: consider updating the dataframe sample too (in the question body)  and add an expected output to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use `pandas.Index.str.find` with `argmax` (assuming your keyword exists uniquely:

```
print(df.iloc[:, :df.columns.str.find("randomnr").argmax()+1])
```

Sample:

```
# df
   A  B  C  D  E  randomnr_123  H  I  J   K
0  1  2  3  4  5             6  7  8  9  10


# df2
   A  B  randomnr_abc  H  I  J   K
0  1  2             6  7  8  9  10
```

Output:

```
print(df.iloc[:, :df.columns.str.find("randomnr").argmax()+1])
   A  B  C  D  E  randomnr_123
0  1  2  3  4  5             6

print(df2.iloc[:, :df2.columns.str.find("randomnr").argmax()+1])
   A  B  randomnr_abc
0  1  2             6
```

Comment: I am sorry i should have been more specific. randomnr is not common accross the subset but all the subsets contains the string randomnr eg: randomnr123 randomnrabc

Comment: helpful if you shared an example with the multiple ``randomr`` columns, with your expected ouptut @nivedangowda

Comment: @nivedangowda Can there be multiple column names with `randomnr`?

Comment: No only one column in all the subsets with column name containing randomnr.

Comment: @sammywemmy I have edited the question. can you please check and let me know if it is helpful?

Comment: @nivedangowda, kindly provide examples of the multiple ``randomr`` substrings, with expected output. visuals are surely much clearer and better.

Comment: @nivedangowda I've updated the answer according to the edit.